# How to make a div stay UNDER the bottom of the page, so visitor can't scroll to it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that stays under the bottom of the page and is invisible there. I mean, you can't scroll to it. I tried to google it, but I just can't make it, neither negative bottom-margin, nor negative bottom, nor relative/absolute positioning couldn't make it...
Could anyone of you help me, please?

Here's a snippet of my site - I wanna "Menu" image to be invisible on the bottom (outside the display area), so it can then slide up when needed.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #780d0d;
  position: absolute;
}
.mainmenu {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 82vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 8vh;
  left: 15vw;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 66px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 66px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 66px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.menu-bottom {
  height: 20%;
  width: 33.2%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
}
.menu-side-holder {
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu-side {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#menu-img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  clear: none;
}
.menu-bottom-slider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 43.5%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="mainmenu">
    <div class="menu-side-holder">
      <div class="menu-side" id="ogloszenia">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="menu-side">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="menu-img" src="img/main4.jpg">
    <div class="menu-side-holder">
      <div class="menu-side">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="menu-side">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom-slider">
      <img id="slider" src="http://s32.postimg.org/xrrmzmohx/slider.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

place your target div as direct child of body (not nested inside other divs) and use this style:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:-100% // or fixed size if height is known
```

Comment: I'm afraird it didn't change anything and you can still scroll to it... I wanted it to stay under all of the displayable content, so no matter how long the page is, it stays under everything and can't be seen.  Here is fiddle of how it works with your advice: https://jsfiddle.net/6v4jw0c5/ Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: in your fiddle you gave absolute position to both menu-bottom-slider and slider (image inside it). The div is out of page (you can check by inspecting element in chrome). Just remove absolute position from image inside it.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to do this is by making it absolute and give it a negative bottom equal to the height of the element like so

```
.menu-bottom-slider{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -(height of element goes here)px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put

`opacity: 0`

on the element and position it where you need it ON the page. Then when you want to use it, use jQuery to change the opacity and animate it.

Comment: That's not what kwojt wanted. If you use `opacity`, elements behind the hidden element become unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the css of your div section.

```
 #divname {
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Your body would look like this.

```
**body{
    margin-bottom:50px;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly working, but you are using `overflow-x`, and you need `overflow-y`.

**EDIT:**

Another way is to set the position of the slider to `fixed`. This means that the position does not depend on the scroll position, so you can't scroll to it:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* you could also change this to overflow-y */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #780d0d;
  position: absolute;
}
.mainmenu {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 82vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 8vh;
  left: 15vw;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 66px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 66px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 66px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.menu-bottom {
  height: 20%;
  width: 33.2%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
}
.menu-side-holder {
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu-side {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#menu-img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  clear: none;
}
.menu-bottom-slider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
#slider {
  position: fixed; /* This fixes the slider, you can't scroll to it! */
  padding-left: 43.5%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="mainmenu">
    <div class="menu-side-holder">
      <div class="menu-side" id="ogloszenia">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="menu-side">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="menu-img" src="img/main4.jpg">
    <div class="menu-side-holder">
      <div class="menu-side">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="menu-side">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bottom-slider">
      <img id="slider" src="http://s32.postimg.org/xrrmzmohx/slider.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, actually I need overflow-x for something else and I tried to avoid overflow-y, because site is going to be longer, and it would not let user to scroll to anything, not just that one element ;P

Comment: You want to scroll vertically? Then you need the element to be fixed.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Imagine a paper roll. You can scroll through it, no matter how long it is, but this div is below the end of the paper roll, so you can never scroll to it. I don't know how to explain this more clear xD